# How to read TFRecord files in TensorFlow from a remote HDFS file system in parallel and efficiently

Tags: tensorflow, parallel-processing, hdfs, tfrecord

I am reading TFRecords data files from a remote HDFS file system through tf.data.TFRecordDataset API in TensorFlow. However, when I increase the num_parallel_reads, say from 1 to 32, not only I don't see improvement in reading speed but I see it takes longer to read the data. Are there any tips to set num_parallel_reads properly to enhance the performance? I know tf.data.TFRecordDataset  uses parallel interleaves which is supposed to be good.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Would like to know if you know how to solve this problem. Because I have the same question.